# Python - Selenium: How to click on the element with text as "Year" within the webpage

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Font
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import datetime
import os
import time
import re

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe")
my_url = 'https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/futures/phelix-at-futures#!/2017/07/24'
browser.get(my_url)
button = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('ng-scope')[-1]
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

It does not give me any error but it is not actually clicking. It should change from month to year, since it is the last element, but it stays there.

Comment: Which button are you trying to click?

Comment: 'Year' button, using inspect seems to be the last 'ng-scope' element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the *url* you have provided to click on the element with text as **Year** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.tabs.filter_wrap.clearfix li.ng-scope:nth-child(3)>a"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='tabs filter_wrap clearfix']//li[@class='ng-scope']/a[contains(.,'Year')]"))).click()
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Font
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import datetime
import os
import time
import re

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe")
my_url = 'https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/futures/phelix-at-futures#!/2017/07/24'
browser.get(my_url)
# wait until button will be present
WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content']/div/div/ul/li[3]/a")))
# find the button and click on it
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/div/ul/li[3]/a")
button.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can peel the same apple in different ways. However, in this very case the better approach would be to use `.find_element_by_link_text()` which is less likely to break. Give it a shot:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.eex.com/en/market-data/power/futures/phelix-at-futures#!/2017/07/24'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Year"))).click()
driver.quit()
```